# Looped Accelerometer Data Calculations Android SDK

Tags: java, android, arraylist, accelerometer, apache-commons

I've been struggling with an app for fall detection for quite some time now. The app runs, but it will freeze up at times, and then resume 10-15 seconds after.
My approach is to do integral calculations (which means I had to import a third party library: Apache Commons). For these integral calculations I need norm values.
I'm calling a method for calculating the norm when the sensor updates:

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event){
    acceleration.setText("\n " + event.values[0] + " , " + event.values[1] + " , " + event.values[2] + " \n");

    x = event.values[0];
    y = event.values[1];
    z = event.values[2];
    if (!checkFall)
        sample(x, y, z);
}
```

calling the *sample function* makes the app run slow (visible through setting text on UI).

*Sample* which is seemingly the root of my problems looks like this:

```
private void sample(double x, double y, double z)
{
    if(xList.size() < 120 && yList.size() < 120 && zList.size() < 120)
    {
        xList.add(x);
        yList.add(y);
        zList.add(z);
    }

    if(xList.size() == 120)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < norm.length; j++)
        {
            norm[j] = sqrt(pow(xList.get(j), 2) + pow(yList.get(j), 2) + pow(zList.get(j), 2));

            for(int p = 0; p < norm.length-1; p++)
            {
                for(int q = 0; q < diff.length; q++)
                {
                    diff[q] = norm[p] - norm[p+1];
                }
            }

            if (norm[j]/9.81 < 0.5)
            {
                final counterClass timer = new counterClass(4000, 20, norm, diff);
                checkFall = true;
                timer.start();
                // if exceeded three times, save the arrayList and register fall
            }
        }
```

(I've tried disabling the timer call when the if statement norm[j]/9.81 < 0.5 has been met, because I thought the error may be in a function that a countdown timer is calling) - but to no help, the app freezes whenever the norm approaches 0.

There are no obvious errors in the logcat, which is why I'm having a hard time narrowing down where the error is. Perhaps I'm accessing the arrays in a terrible way?

If there is any missing information you'd like me to provide or if my questions is too vague, please let me know.

EDIT:

Counter Class

```
public counterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval, double[] norm, double[] diff) {
    super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval); // Duration & how often onTick should be called
    nor = norm;
    dif = diff;
}

public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
    listFall(); // Adding accelerometer data to fall list array List each time its called
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            vCheck(nor,dif);
        }
    }).start();
}
```

Comment: The SQLite errors are not related to your code. Do you even use sqlite anywhere?

Comment: Nope :) Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: Can you share your code of `counterClass` (at least what you do in the constructor?)

Comment: The app does however, freeze even if I disable the counter class - so I assume that the problem doesn't lie there.

Comment: Your interval is 20 ms, right? So you create a new thread every 20ms. I recommend that you add [Hugo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/hugo) and annotate the different methods with @DebugLog so that you can see what method is exactly responsible for the freeze and what parameters are given to that long running method.

Comment: if you remove the sample() call, does it freeze as well?

Comment: If I remove the sample call, the app doesn't freeze.

Comment: ok, try to divide and conquer: comment out everything except the first if statement in your sample and check. If that works, fine. Continue by enabling the next if but comment out some loops... continue until you find a line that causes the issue

Comment: The adding of values to three ArrayLists are apparently quite computational. The device updates the UI text field much slower up until the ArrayLists sizes reach 120.

Comment: I could imagine that you could speed up this by initializing the arrays with a size of 120. If I recall correctly, the lists have a default size of 12 or so.

Comment: Thanks. It helped!
Also, doing the integral and sample calculations on other threads have made the app run smoothly.